# keras data generator not printing anything

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm implementing a DataGenerator in Keras. It seems to work well, however, when I try to print anything wihle training it doesn't output anything.

Here goes a minimal working example of my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from datetime import datetime

def my_print(s):
    print(s)
    with open('log.log', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(datetime.now()) + s + '\n')

class DataFeaturesGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, batch_size=32, n_data=1000):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_data = n_data
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(self.n_data / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        X = np.random.normal(size=(self.batch_size, 2048))
        y = np.zeros((self.batch_size,2), dtype=np.int)
        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        my_print('#'*10)
        my_print('epoch finished')
        my_print('#'*10)
```

And then I run it as follows:

```
train_feat_gen = DataFeaturesGenerator()
eval_feat_gen = DataFeaturesGenerator()

n_classes=2
base_model = InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=None,
pooling='avg')
input_feats = Input(base_model.output_shape[1:])
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(input_feats)
predictions = Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

shallow_model = Model(inputs=input_feats, outputs=predictions)

shallow_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = shallow_model.fit(epochs=30, x=train_feat_gen, validation_data=eval_feat_gen) 
# tried with workers=0 or default, nothing changes. Same for verbose =0, 1 or 2
```

Those print messages are shown for the first invocation (when I call the constructor on the first time) but they don't appear while training: the output is the same as usual.

I need to print some info for debugging purposes. I'm sure there is something I'm not taking into account.

I'm running TensorFlow 2.1.0, therefore fit_generator is deprecated, just fit is enough. However, also tried it with 2.0.0, 1.15.2 and 1.14.0 but still doesn't work.

`my_print` function only is being executed on the first call, on constructor, during the training, nothing is printed on standard output nor logfile.

**Update**: run all this code on Google Colab and it works ok.

**Work around**: As it worked on Google colab, I checked its TensorFlow version and installed the same locally: `pip install tensorflow==2.2.0-rc2`
 and it worked ok.

Comment: You have to share all the methods in your DataFeaturesGenerator class and at least the call to fit or fit_generator function of your model for us to spot the problem.

Comment: I added more code to the example. My first qestion anyway is: should I see this output while training?

Comment: After removing some of the file-related stuff, I have just tried this with TF 1.15.2 and it works just fine. So it's either TF 2.1.0 that makes the difference or something in your file-related code. Please provide a more minimal [mcve], without the file stuff.

Comment: I removed lots of useless code for the example. The problem is still there :/

Comment: @Hendrik thanks for your answer. I updated the code, also tested it with tf 2.0.0 and 1.15.2 and it still doesn't work

Comment: After changing `input_feats = Input(shape=(2048,))` and using `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` this works just fine for me (without GPU support). Perhaps you have a more general setup problem.

Comment: I solved those bugs on example code, sorry for those. Also run it on multiple TF versions without any change. I'm running those on jupyter notebook, without GPU support